# How to reset Informatica Admin Console password on 9.6.0?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, forgot-password

Informatica Server was setup at our local server, but unfortunately nobody remembers the Admin Console password for user "Administrator".

1.) Using pmpasswd, I created an encrypted password and replaced the current one in PO_USERINFO table "POU_PASSWORD" field, in the database I found on my "Informatica_9.6.0_Services" log file, but the service would not restart. I had to revert it back for the service to run again.

2.)  I have tried using default user name/ password combinations but they aren't working

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to reset a lost admin password is at the database level. Informatica Support has a process for this if you contact them.

Do not alter the database yourself!!